# modern prefered way to pass member function to std:function interface

Tags: c++

having a callback registering function:
`void Foo::registerCallBack(std::function<void(Bar*)> f)`

what is the preferred c++ way to pass a member function as argument?

```
class Baz{
public:
  void cb(Bar*);

  Baz (Foo& foo){
    // using lambda:
    foo.registerCallBack([this](auto b) { this->cb(b); });
    // using bind
    foo.registerCallBack( std::bind( &Baz::cb, this, std::placeholders::_1) );
  }
};
```

Are there other possibilities?
That are the implications of the methods (e.g. in terms of overhead)? Any reasonable differences?

Comment: And soon [std::bind_front](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front)!

Comment: I like the `std::bind` version, but only when using the placeholder without an explicitly qualified namespace name.

Comment: *lambda* is preferable because implies less overhead and might enable more compiler optimizations.

Comment: @KonradRudolph i do not really like to clutter my namespace with 2-letter symbols just for a single usage of a symbol

Comment: @BiagioFesta can you elaborate on this in more detail please?

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Well, it is hard to do a deep benchmark analysis, because of more context would be required. However, *generally* `std::bind` seems to involve a small overhead (probably to guarantee the correct type-erasure). You might directly check in the [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/88aZFj). In that scenario, `bind` seems to require even a heap-allocation. Moreover, [on this naive benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/cXxZHIZSJM6ZiaQKj6ysyQNQ83c) you can see how the compiler can optimize en empty function. But again, those are just general assumptions.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch Yes. `std::placeholders` is an explicit exception to the usual rule not to open namespaces. It drastically increases readability.